# Auto focus on search box of jQuery DataTable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am unable to find a way to auto focus on jQuery Datatable's Search Box on page load.

The problem here is that this Text box is not given a ID and so i'm unable to access it.

Can someone help me with this issue.

An example of Datatable is at https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-options.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datatabelID [type='search']").focus();
});
```

or

```
$("div.dataTables_filter input").focus();
```

Just use your datatable Id with the above selector, and you are bale to access the search textbox.

Comment: try using this : $('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();

Comment: Cool ! updated my answer!! Mark this as a answer if it's helpfull @Reddy

Comment: in my case I used "Individual column searching (text inputs)" from datatables page,  so I added class="inputName" to my first <th> inside <tfoot>  and after my datatable code, I added this function:....................................................................................                                            
 // Autofocus in first input (Name)
$(function () {
 $("#inputName [type='text']").focus();
});