# Datatables focus input search on Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using datatables on bootstrap3 modal, i want focus on search input filter. when i click button, open the modal with datatables.

i've tried worked but not datatables on modal.

[Auto focus on search box of jQuery DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132440/auto-focus-on-search-box-of-jquery-datatable)

[datatable search field always focus stop all other action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167168/datatable-search-field-always-focus-stop-all-other-action/51437359)

Answer (score 0):

This is sample code,

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employees</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lookup').DataTable(
    {
        "responsive": true
        });
    $('#lookup_filter input').focus()
    //$('#lookup_filter [type="search"]').focus()
    });
</script>

<button class="btn-warning fa fa-search" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Emply">Employee</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="Emply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="bg-warning modal-title" style="text-align:center" id="myModalLabel">List Employee</h4>
        </div></strong>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <table id="lookup" class="display responsive" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>No</th>
                      <th>ID</th>
                      <th>Employee</th>
                      <th>Saldo</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>                
                    <tr>
                      <td>1</td>
                      <td>40001</td>
                      <td>JOHN THOR</td>
                      <td>10000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>40002</td>
                      <td>JOHN WICK</td>
                      <td>20000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>2</td>
                      <td>40003</td>
                      <td>JOHN CENA</td>
                      <td>20000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
   $('div.dataTables_filter input').focus();
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).